# Making non-WSDL SOAP requests in Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, soap

I'm trying to figure out how to make a SOAP request using Node.js.
I have a piece of code working perfectly in PHP; I would like to replicate the very same functionality using Node.js.

This is the working PHP piece of code:

```
    $url = "http://192.168.0.1/app/rpc.pl";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $TicketID = 10;

        $client = new SoapClient(
            null,
            array(
                'location' => $url,
                'uri' => "Core",
                'trace' => 1,
                'login' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'style' => SOAP_RPC,
                'use' => SOAP_ENCODED
            )
        );

        $sql =
        $TicketDetails = $client->__soapCall("Dispatch",
            array($username, $password,
                "TicketObject", "TicketGet",
                "TicketID", $TicketID,
            ));
```

This is my actual Node.js code, which is just supposed to just create a client, for the moment:

```
var soap = require('soap');

var args = {
            location: "http://192.168.0.1/app/rpc.pl",
            login: "user",
            password: "password",
            uri: "Core",
            trace: 1,
            style: SOAP_RPC,
            use: SOAP_ENCODED
        };

soap.createClient(null, args, function(err, client) {    
    ...
});
```

The output I get in Node is:

```
Error: Invalid WSDL URL: http://192.168.0.1/app/rpc.pl

Code: 411
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you [checked out any tutorial/guide](https://medium.com/@caleblemoine/how-to-perform-soap-requests-with-node-js-4a9627070eb6)? Also, _"But so far nothing in Node.js is working"_ is a terrible description of your issue. What actually happens? Any specific errors? Btw, I think that `SOAP_RPC` and `SOAP_ENCODED` are PHP-specific constants.

Comment: I've tried many different approaches but none worked. It seems unclear to me how to make non-WSDL requests without writing unclear and workaround-ish code. The PHP code posted above is working just fine without including any additional XML code. I'd like to replicate the same simple client in Node.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've updated the Node.js output. I've tried to send the same request without including the two PHP constants, and what I get is a 411 error.